# No JRE found. Please make sure $RIDER_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME point to valid JRE installation

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-20.04, rider

I want to run JetBrains Rider 2021.3 by `rider.sh` but I get this error:

```
No JRE found. Please make sure $RIDER_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME point to valid JRE installation.
```

I used this commands:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
sudo apt install default-jre
```

and my current java version is :

```
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

but I cant start rider.

Comment: You need to set one of those environment variables.  Like the error message says.

Comment: Since you are using OpenJDK 11 installed from the Ubuntu package manager, this will probably do what is needed `$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/`.